# Simple open3 example not working

Tags: perl, ipc, ipcopen3

I am trying to make a Master perl script calling children perl script and interacting through a pipe.

I have write this code for the master :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open3;

my @children;

for my $i ( 0 .. 4 ) {
    print "Master: " . $i . ", I summon you\n";

    $children[$i] = {};

    $children[$i]->{'pid'} = open3( my $CH_IN, my $CH_OUT, my $CH_ERR, 'perl child.pl -i ' . $i );

    $children[$i]->{'_STDIN'}  = $CH_IN;
    $children[$i]->{'_STDOUT'} = $CH_OUT;
    $children[$i]->{'_STDERR'} = $CH_ERR;

    my $line = readline $children[$i]->{'_STDOUT'};
    print $line ;

}

print "Master: Go fetch me the sacred crown\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. 4 ) {
    $children[$i]->{'_STDIN'}->write("fetch the sacred crown\n");
    my $line = readline $children[$i]->{'_STDIN'};
    print $line ;
}

print "Master: Thanks. Now die!!!\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. 4 ) {
    $children[$i]->{'_STDIN'}->write("die !!\n");
    my $line = readline $children[$i]->{'_STDIN'};
    print $line ;
}
```

And this one for the child :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Getopt::Long ;

my $cmdline_id ;

GetOptions ('i=s' => \$cmdline_id) ;

my $id = $cmdline_id ;

exit 1 if !defined $id ;

print "I am $id, and I am awaken\n" ;

while(<STDIN>) {
    print STDOUT $id . ': Master ask me to ' . $_ ;

    if ($_ =~ /exit/oi) {
        exit 0 ;
    }
}
```

But when I launch the Master he just hung while reading the response from the child.

Any idea about what I did wrong, and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Say `$|=1` near the beginning of the child process to allow the child to print without waiting for the output buffer to fill up.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, passing undef for the third arg (as you are) doesn't do what you want. You need to initialise the variable using Symbol's `gensym`.

```
use Symbol qw( gensym );

my %child;
$child{pid} = open3(
    $child{'_STDIN' } = gensym,
    $child{'_STDOUT'} = gensym,
    $child{'_STDERR'} = gensym,
    'perl', 'child.pl', '-i' => $i
);

$children[$i] = \%child;
```